# Amazon Dax Failed to retrieve endpoints Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I'm getting the following error with my 3 node DAX Cluster:
Failed to retrieve endpoints
Traceback (most recent call last):

My setup:
- Private Lambdas
- Python 3.6
- amazon-dax-client
- Config settings - timeout 300ms, max retries 5
- vpc has 3 subnets
- The DAX cluster has 3 x r4.large nodes

This error happens intermittently - it still "works" most of the time but it is alarming given how often it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DAX Python client up to and including 1.0.6 is a bit too sensitive when checking the health of cluster nodes and considers them unhealthy when they're not. The errors are benign, but annoying. This will be fixed in an upcoming release.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, good to know - do you know when we can expect to see that release?

Comment: Also would you say it is the same for puts that this error is “benign”

Comment: Sorry, "soon" is the most I can say. As for puts, it should still be benign - the call will fail before it ever reaches DAX.